# Sci-fi book about a species of primitive creatures, which evolve into a technologically advanced society seeking to conquer whole galaxies

Tags: story-identification, books

The plot of the book is the following. On a planet lives a primitive species of sheep-like creatures, which evolve into a technologically advanced society. In the process of their evolution, over centuries and millennia, there were many local wars, which became ever more sophisticated, pushing them to the brink of extinction.

Once one of the war faring groups became dominant, it started to subjugate the whole planetary population of sheep, making them work to become even more powerful and technologically advanced, until becoming an industrial society and reaching to the stars to dominate the local solar system. Their aim was to dominate even more civilizations, then reaching to become an interstellar type civilization starving for even more resources and space.

In order to feed their endless growing population and to feed their war machine, they were reaching out to conquer whole galaxies and eventually the whole universe, by creating wormholes and other advanced technologies... eventually reaching the Milky Way and planet Earth... (I am not sure about the last part about reaching Earth and that's why I am so eager to read the book again to know how it ends).

I did read the book between 2002-2008. Unfortunately the title and author are not known.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall any details about the cover? Also, is the species described as "sheep-like" within the book itself?

Comment: Honorable mention for [*Dragon's Egg*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon%27s_Egg) by [Robert L. Forward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_L._Forward) which features an alien species with **very** little development, who upon contact with humans experience a series of revolutionary social & technological shifts over the course of hours which put them far ahead of humanity. No galactic conquests, though, :)

Comment: Yes, while Dragon's Egg by Robert L. Forward is not the OPs book, it certainly IS a fantastic read, (and the sequel)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect that’s Peter F Hamilton’s [Commonwealth Saga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonwealth_Saga), which consists of *Pandora’s Star* and *Judas Unchained*.

> When the Second Chance arrives and begins to explore what appears to
> be an enclosure generator, an unknown mechanism
> shuts it down and the barrier around the star disappears. Formerly
> imprisoned inside is an extremely warlike and aggressive species, a
> race that comes to be called "the Primes". They consist of intelligent
> "immotiles" that breed and control vast armies of sub-sentient
> "motiles" via electronically extended neural interfaces. The few
> immotiles constantly vie with each other for territories and
> resources, and by the time of the story, the strongest uses the
> technology gleaned by analysis of the human's wormhole-generation
> techniques to destroy all the other Prime immotiles and thus become
> the only one remaining Prime: MorningLightMountain.

Comment: If OP's description of the book is anywhere close to reality, then it won't be the Commonwealth Saga. MLM never got that far.

Comment: @AhmedTawfik I’m assuming that the whole third paragraph of the question is a misremembering of a book read fifteen years ago. The first and second paragraphs are a very good fit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am very grateful, as the Book has been found, and I have already re-ordered it... Thanks to all involved...appreciate it a lot.